# How implement auto-fill in input form

Tags: java, jsp, solr, autocomplete, autofill

I have an `ArrayList<String> products` where i load them to an input text

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option id="AL9001">AL9001</option>
  <option id="AV8932">AV8932</option>
  <option id="BVE0932">BVE0932</option>
  etc...
</select>
```

the size of the ArrayList is quite big (2000 elements) so it's not so easy to scroll down 2000 elements to find what you want.. How can I implement an auto-fill fuctionality, where the user starts write sth and the possible elements are shown.. I searched and I found only an html attribute `autocomplete`where it doesn't work for my case..

One other solution I found is [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) where it may fit as my project is build with Tomcat and jsps.. Is there any other way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either the [datalist](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-autocomplete-dropdowns-datalist-element) HTML5 element, or the jQuery-ui [autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) widget (if you need to support old browsers). I would also suggest to validate the input before submit, as both datalist and autocomplete work only for `<input>` and not for `<select>`, so the user can type anything there. (Not mentioning the obvious server-side validation of the submitted values.)